# aws java sdk ClientExecutionTimeoutException

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk

We are getting `ClientExecutionTimeoutException` when using below values

```
 ClientConfiguration config = new ClientConfiguration();
 config.setClientExecutionTimeout(100);
 config.setRequestTimeout(100);
```

This is in health check call which checks if bucket exists

```
amazonS3.doesBucketExistV2(bucketName);
```

Has anyone faced similar issue and what could be solution for this. I checked in POC and if I set it to 400, error disappears. Using aws-java-sdk-s3 v 1.11 and java 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the timeout is set in milliseconds, you have set a very low execution and request timeout.

I would recommend you to:

- Set it to 400 ms.
- Test how much time it takes for your command to execute:

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
amazonS3.doesBucketExistV2(bucketName);
long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long timeElapsed = endTime - startTime;
System.out.println("Execution time in milliseconds: " + timeElapsed);
```

- If the time elapsed is above 100 ms, then your code fails for 100 ms because it is supposed to be.
- Set your timeout according to your needs and you are done.